# implied subject within a noun clause

Tags: nouns, clauses

I recently came across a sentence in an academic text that was similar in structure to "I eat what is considered healthy." I interpreted the grammar as "what is considered healthy" being a noun clause. Someone then pointed out to me that a clause needs a subject and verb, and "what" should be the subordinator, not the subject.

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: The clause contains a verb ("is") and a subject ("what"). What is the problem?

Comment: There are four main types of noun complement clauses: infinitives, gerunds, _that_-clauses, and _wh_-clauses (also known as embedded questions or headless relatives). _What is considered healthy_ is a _wh_-clause functioning as the direct object of _eat_. As a clause, it has a subject (_what_) and a verb (_is considered_).

Answer (score 1):

> I eat what is considered healthy

In this sentence, "what" serves a dual purpose as a subordinator and a subject.

Answer (score 0):

"what is considered healthy" is a nominal relative clause, as it can be broken down into:

- the things (noun phrase) that are considered healthy (relative clause), or
- any food (noun phrase) that is considered healthy (relative clause)